# MongoDB trying to connect to localhost, Why?

Tags: java, mongodb

I am currently developing a Java application connected to a remote MongoDB databse.

I have implemented the authentication methods fallowing the mongo guides:

```
MongoCredential credential = MongoCredential.createScramSha1Credential(username, credentialDatabase, password.toCharArray());
MongoClient client = new MongoClient(new ServerAddress(hostname, port), Arrays.asList(credential));
mongoDatabase = client.getDatabase(database);
```

The app connect properly to the database but there is a thing i can't understand.It connects well to the remote server,but I don't know why it try to connect to localhost:27017.

```
2016-03-07 16:13:29.662  INFO 12507 --- [*.*.*:25015] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:1, serverValue:29}] to *.*.*.*:25015

2016-03-07 16:13:29.687  INFO 12507 --- [*.*.*:25015] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=*.*.*.*:25015, type=STANDALONE, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion{versionList=[3, 2, 3]}, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=4, maxDocumentSize=16777216, roundTripTimeNanos=24485426}


2016-03-07 16:13:30.062  INFO 12507 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Cluster created with settings {hosts=[localhost:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500}


2016-03-07 16:13:30.220  INFO 12507 --- [localhost:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server localhost:27017

com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
```

So, how can I tell it I don't want to connect to localhost ?

Thanks

Comment: can you post the `hostname` string?

Comment: This should answer your question.  https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongod/#bin.mongod

Comment: the hostname string is the ip address of my server

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can exclude Mongo auto connect/(localhost:27017) by adding below annotation on spring boot `Application.java`.

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={MongoAutoConfiguration.class})
public class Application {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted; this was exactly the information that helped me.

Comment: Now you put the parameters into @SpringbootApplication annotation. For Reactive Mongo there is also another autoconfiguration class  - ```@SpringBootApplication(
    exclude = {MongoAutoConfiguration.class, MongoReactiveAutoConfiguration.class})```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if this will help.

If you are using SpringBoot 1.4 and you will not have a bean for MongoClient in the context auto configuration will create MongoClient using default configuration.

```
@Configuration
---->@ConditionalOnClass(MongoClient.class)<----
@EnableConfigurationProperties(MongoProperties.class)
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(type = "org.springframework.data.mongodb.MongoDbFactory")
public class MongoAutoConfiguration {
...
    @Bean
    ---->@ConditionalOnMissingBean<----
    public MongoClient mongo() throws UnknownHostException {
        this.mongo = this.properties.createMongoClient(this.options, this.environment);
        return this.mongo;
    }
...
```

So you have 3 options:

1. Exclude auto configuration for mongo.
2. Expose MongoClient as a bean in context.
3. Use default way of configuration for SpringBoot/Mongo and relay on auto configuration to create MongoClient for you:

   `spring.data.mongodb.host=
   spring.data.mongodb.port=
   spring.data.mongodb.database=
   spring.data.mongodb.username=
   spring.data.mongodb.password=`

Answer (score 3):

That's Spring Boot's Auto Configuration kicking in. You can disable it by extending your `@SpringBootApplication` annotation like this:

```java
@SpringBootApplication(exclude={MongoAutoConfiguration.class})
```

Comment: is it the correct way to do it? in my Spring Boot project, it's still trying to connect to localhost:27017.